# writing to an excel(.xlsx/.xls) file using angular4

Tags: angular

I have an array list of objects, i want to write those data to an excel file from a specific cell. I tried using exceljs node modules but getting errors. How to achieve this using angular 4.

Comment: Error--? Can you show us?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `xlsx`. You can find a guide [here](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/tree/4109caeadd95baca58c7c2481aebf2014ae462bd/demos/angular2) for angular 2 / 4 / 5 / 6 and ionic.

Comment: I tried using xlsx module and able to generate the excel file,but i unable to add any styling component to the cell. Can you please tell which module is best to achieve the above with style/formatting of an excel.